# Relation that is reflexive but not transitive or similar.

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

During class we had to come up with relations that are reflexive, but are not transitive or similar. I know the definitions of these terms. If we have a relation defined by the triple

$$r = (A, B, R)$$

where $R$ is a subset of the cartesian product

$$R \subseteq A \times B = \{ (a, b) \hspace{0.1cm} | \hspace{0.1cm} a \in A, b \in B \}$$

it is

$$\text{reflexive: if} \hspace{.1cm} x  \hspace{.1cm} r \hspace{.1cm} x, \forall \hspace{.1cm} x \in A$$

$$\text{transitive: if} \hspace{.1cm} x \hspace{.1cm} r \hspace{.1cm} y \hspace{.1cm} \text{and} \hspace{.1cm} y \hspace{.1cm} r \hspace{.1cm} z, \text{then} \hspace{.1cm} x \hspace{.1cm} r \hspace{.1cm}z, \hspace{.1cm} \forall \hspace{.1cm} x, y, z \in A$$

$$\text{symmetric: if} \hspace{.1cm} x \hspace{.1cm} r \hspace{.1cm} y, \text{then} \hspace{.1cm} y \hspace{.1cm} r \hspace{.1cm} x, \hspace{.1cm} \forall \hspace{.1cm} x, y \in A$$

However, I couldn't come up with any such example. Are there any such examples on the basic numeric sets $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $r$ is not even a relation.  $R$ is.

Comment: @GrahamKemp So we can call $R$ the relation since it defines the graph of the relation, right? If so, what can I call $r$? Like, what is its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{ (x,x), (y,y), (z,z), (x,y), (y,z) \}$

Comment: What is this set of pairs? What exactly does it mean?

Comment: @user1502 a relation on a set $A$ is a subset of $A \times A.$ That set of pairs is the relation itself

Comment: Wake up, @user1502, it's an answer to your request.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking... I see it now.